# Is there a monotone sequence that converges and has a divergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to figure out an example of a monotone sequence that converges and has a divergent subsequence, but I can't think of one.

I know the monotone sequence has to go to 0. Is it even possible for it to have a divergent subsequence?

Answer (score 2):

A sequence that converges *cannot* have a divergent subsequence: every subsequence converges to the same limit. Unless you're in some crazy space of convergence, such as defining $a_n\rightarrow a$ by requiring only the even term subsequence $a_{2n}$ converges.

Proof: If $a_n$ converges to $a$, monotone or otherwise that means that $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists a $N>0$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$. If $a_{n_k}$ is a subsequence, then clearly $|a_{n_k}-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n_k\geq N$, so that there's an $M$ such that $|a_{n_k}-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $k\geq M$ . So $a_{n_k}\rightarrow a$.

Also the tag "monotone-class-theorem" is for something else entirely.

Comment: In addition, a monotone sequence that has a convergent subsequence is itself convergent.